# Apache server cannot accessed externally after start monitorix service, it was work

Tags: apache, ubuntu-server

searched via google, no very specific and helpful answers.

Set up apache server on ubuntu server, and SET server's ip in DMZ in the router,
also assign a domain name for that. (eg. www.mypage.com)

for the last 2 weeks, it works fine, the server can be reached remotely from WAN.
(type www.mypage.com shows the home page)

however, since started monitorix service last night, apache server stop working.

type www.mypage.com shows cannot connect, but type in www.mypage.com:8080/monitorix, it shows monitorix graph page.

this means DMZ works, also used ssh to connect to www.mypage.com, it can access my ubuntu server.

use sudo netstat -plunt | grep apache2, fond apache2 is listening port 80
sudo netstat -plunt | grep monitorix, it is listening port 8080

decide to uninstall monitorix.
after use sudo apt-get purge monitorix, still cannot solve the problem

apache web root is /var/www/html
monitorix web root is /var/lib/monitorix/www

i believe the web root is still using monitorix's web root.

any ideas how to fix this? cheers.

Answer (score 0):

reset the router into factory solved the problem, but problem happen again.

finally, find out it is my NAS system creates automatic port forwarding.
disabled DMZ in router, and set port forwarding service in it.

issue solved, and my pages works fine.